# How do I access the sources from browser console?

Tags: javascript, browser, console, resources, firefox-addon-webextensions

I wonder how I can access the Sources listed in the Debugger-Tab **using the Console** in Firefox.

Basically, I want to retrieve their URLs **using JavaScript** for a custom browser extension.

[image: Sources]

Comment: I do not think there is a way a website can programmatically access the firefox dev tools? Surely if you control the website you already know all the sources?

Comment: It's not the website that accesses the tools, it's the client's browser. I am not in control of the website.

Comment: That's not the way your are supposed to use it. It keeps track of all ressource called on the page. You can see an other method : like scrapping <headers> to get ressources link. Or use an external lib. Short answer :there is no dedicated debugger chrome function accessible throw DOM

Comment: What do you mean by `scrapping <headers>`, and can you elaborate on potential candidates for external libs, whatever this is supposed to mean?
I do understand that this is not the intended usage, but I am less interested in intentions than I am in possible actions ;-)

Comment: Use performance.getEntries() in the content script.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you very much!